# How do I make a JavaScript promise return something other than a promise?

Tags: javascript

I have a spec from a client for an implementation of a method in a module:

```
 // getGenres():
 //  Returns a promise. When it resolves, it returns an array.
```

If given an array of genres,

```
['comedy', 'drama', 'action']
```

Here is a skeleton method with a promise:

```
MovieLibrary.getGenres = function() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    /* missing implementation */
  });

  return promise;
};
```

Can the promise be made to return the data found in the genres? Is there a better way to achieve the spec description?

Comment: Promises don't "return" values, they pass them to a callback (which you supply with .then()). The spec simply sounds confused to me. It's probably trying to say that you're supposed to do `resolve([genre1, genre2, ...]);` inside the promise implementation.

Comment: A promise can also be _rejected_ (instead of resolved) in case of an error/exception, and in such case the returned promise is 'caught' with the `Promise.catch`. In case of using `async` / `await` syntax one should use the `try-catch` block to enclose the _awaited_ statement(s). Note there is also a `Promise.finally`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't understanding how promises are used.  You return a promise.  Then, later when your code resolves the promise, it resolves it with a result and that result is passed to the `.then()` handler attached to the promise:

```
MovieLibrary.getGenres = function() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    /* missing implementation */
    resolve(result);
  });

  return promise;
};

MovieLibrary.getGenres().then(function(result) {
    // you can access the result from the promise here
});
```

Comment: Probably, you don't understand why this might be needed. In environment, like React Native with Redux with Realm, I have to put initial state to Redux createStore. It should be fetched from Realm, but it returns promise. I just want to block until it returns data as this should be very fast and simple. Instead I get problems how to combine Realm promises and usual JSON object for createStore()

Comment: @likern Browser Javascript can't block... end of story.

Answer (score 59):

*Updated answer for ES2017*

### The method will still return a promise, but you can use `const value = await (the promise)` to assign a value to a variable

`await` stops executing until the Promise has resolved (ie, has a value). Unlike using `.then()` you can just keep `await`ing values as you run various functions that return promises, and execution continues onto the next line (this is called 'direct style). It's also **much** nicer to look at than `.then()` everywhere, since it's consistent with the rest of JavaScript.

```
// Example function that returns a Promise that will resolve after 2 seconds
var getGenres = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(['comedy', 'drama', 'action'])
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// We start an 'async' function to use the 'await' keyword
(async function(){
  var result = await getGenres()
  console.log('Woo done!', result)

  // But the best part is, we can just keep awaiting different stuff, without ugly .then()s
  var somethingElse = await getSomethingElse()
  var moreThings = await getMoreThings()
})()
```

[Await is supported in all current browsers and node](http://caniuse.com/#search=await)

Comment: Oh hey wow look, 3 SE questions on this subject and finally we have an actual answer!

Comment: Babel will also compile ES6 async/await to ES5 compatible code. Common Component within frameworks like Angular.

Comment: `value = await (the promise)` requires one to be inside an async context, thus defeating the purpose

Comment: @smac89 You can use an IIFE or newer node supports top level await.

Comment: Got it. I was using the repl, so I had to launch it with `node --experimental-repl-await`

Answer (score 1):

The way I like to do it is to create a let variable and assign the 'then' result to that variable.  Const won't work because it will give you an error.  It will be like **`let value_result = function_that_returns_promise.then(result => value_result = result)`**

For your example, I made the method into a function for simplicity:

```
const genres = ['comedy', 'drama', 'action'];

function getGenres() {
  var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
     let result = genres[0]  //just picking out the first one as example
     resolve(result)
  })
  return promise
}

const result_as_promise = getGenres()
console.log(result_as_promise);

//output:
//Promise { 'comedy' }

let result_as_value = getGenres().then(result => result_as_value = result)

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log(result_as_value);
}, 0);

//output:
//comedy
```

You have to use setTimeout if you are running through node (otherwise you'll get undefined error due to racing condition); if running it in browser console, then you prob don't need the setTimeout.

Comment: I don't think you need to assign the promise to `result_as_value` in `let result_as_value = getGenres().then(...)`.  Just declaring the variable and the assignment in the `then(result => result_as_value = result)` suffice. The reason this works is because the callback to `setTimeout(...)` executes _after_ all of the other user code has executed, which includes resolving the `getGenres()` promise. This is related to how the `event loop` works. See how Node.js does it, https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/